# DDD: Domain Objects Structure

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, aggregateroot, value-objects

I'm new to DDD and I want to clearly understand each domain object structure and role:

1. Aggregate Root:

   1.1. The only contact point the client can interact with the domain objects, the client should not be able to modify or create new Entities or value objects whiteout the aggregate root? (Yes/No)

   1.2. Can an aggregate root contain only value objects ? for example User root, it contain only address, phone, things which are value objects as far as I understand. So is it a sign of bad design when your aggregate root contain only value objects? shall it contain only entities and via entities interact with value objects?
2. Entities: Shall the entities contain only value objects? or it can also contain other entities? can you give me a simple example please ?
3. Value Objects: shall I go ahead and encapsulate every primitive type in an value object? I can go deep and make every primitive type as an value object, for example: PhoneNumber can be a string or an value object which contains country code, number. the same thing can be applied to all other primitive type value such as name, email. So where to draw the line ? where to say "Ok I'm going to deep", or going deep is the right way of doing DDD?
4. Factories: Do I really need them? I can go ahead and write an static method within the domain object which knows more precisely how to construct it, am I doing wrong ?

Sorry for the long questions, but I'm feeling little lost despite of continues reading, if you can help me I would be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer all your questions:

1.1. The only contact point the client can interact with the domain objects, the client should not be able to modify or create new Entities or value objects whiteout the aggregate root? (Yes/No)

**Entities live within ARs and allowing the client to create them would violate encapsulation, so for entities you are correct, ARs create their own entities which don't get exposed to the outside (copies/immutable views could be).**

**On the other hand, value objects are generally immutable and therefore there's no harm in having them supplied to the AR as data inputs.**

**In general all modifications needs to go through the AR so that the AR is aware of the modification. In special situations the AR could detect modifications within it's cluster by listening to events raised by internal entities when it's impractical to go through the root.**

1.2. Can an aggregate root contain only value objects ? for example User root, it contain only address, phone, things which are value objects as far as I understand. So is it a sign of bad design when your aggregate root contain only value objects? shall it contain only entities and via entities interact with value objects?

**Favor value objects as much as you can. It's not unusual for all parts of an AR being modeled as values. However, there's no limitation or law stating whether or not an AR should have only values or entities, use the composition that's fit to your use case.**

Entities: Shall the entities contain only value objects? or it can also contain other entities? can you give me a simple example please ?

**Same answer as above, no limitation nor law.**

Value Objects: shall I go ahead and encapsulate every primitive type in an value object? I can go deep and make every primitive type as an value object, for example: PhoneNumber can be a string or an value object which contains country code, number. the same thing can be applied to all other primitive type value such as name, email. So where to draw the line ? where to say "Ok I'm going to deep", or going deep is the right way of doing DDD?

**Primitive obsession is worst than value object obsession in my experience. The cost of wrapping a value is quite low in general, so when in doubt I'd model an explicit type. This could save you a lot of refactoring down the road.**

Factories: Do I really need them? I can go ahead and write an static method within the domain object which knows more precisely how to construct it, am I doing wrong ?

**Static factory methods on ARs are quite common as a mean to be more expressive and follow the UL more closely. For instance, I just modeled as use case today where we had to "start a group audit". Implemented a `GroupAudit.start` static factory method.**

**Factory methods on ARs for other ARs are also quite common, such as `var post = forum.post(author, content)` for instance, where `Post` is a seperate AR than `Forum`.**

**When the process requires some complex collaborators then you may consider a standalone factory though since you may not want clients to know how to provide and setup those collaborators.**

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to DDD and I want to clearly understand each domain object structure and role

Your best starting point is "the blue book" (Evans, 2003).

For this question, the two important chapters to review are chapter 5 ("A model expressed in software") and chapter 6 ("the life cycle of a domain object").

ENTITIES and VALUE OBJECTS are two patterns described in chapter 5, which is to say that they are patterns that commonly arise when we are modeling a domain.  The TL;DR version: ENTITIES are used to represent relationships in the domain that change over time.  VALUE OBJECTS are domain specific data structures.

AGGREGATES and FACTORIES are patterns described in chapter 6, which is to say that they are patterns that commonly arise when we are trying to manage the life cycle of the domain object.  It's common that modifications to domain entities may be distributed across multiple sessions, so we need to think about how we store information in the past and reload that information in the future.

---

> The only contact point the client can interact with the domain objects, the client should not be able to modify or create new Entities or value objects whiteout the aggregate root?

Gray area.  "Creation patterns are weird." The theory is that you always copy information into the domain model via an aggregate root.  But when the aggregate root you need doesn't exist yet, then what?  There are a number of different patterns that people use here to create the new root entity from nothing.

That said - we don't expect the application to be directly coupled to the internal design of the aggregate.  This is standard "best practice" OO, with the application code coupled to the model's interface without being coupled to the model's implementation/data structure.

> Can an aggregate root contain only value objects ?

The definition of the root entity in the aggregate may include references to other entities in the same aggregate.  Evans explicitly refers to "entities other than the root"; in order to share information with an entity other than the root, there must be some way to traverse references from the root to these non-root entities.

> Shall the entities contain only value objects?

The definition of an entity may include references to other entities (including the root entity) in the same aggregate.

> shall I go ahead and encapsulate every primitive type in an value object?

"It depends" - in a language like java, value objects are an affordance that make it easy for the compiler to give you early feed back about certain kinds of mistakes.

This is especially true if you have validation concerns.  We'd like to validate (or parse) information once, rather than repeating the same check every where (duplication), and having validated vs unvalidated data be detectably different reduces the risk that unvalidated data leaks into code paths where it is not handled correctly.

Having a value object also reduces the number of places that need to change if you decide the underlying data structure needs improvement, and the value object gives you an easily guessed place to put functions/methods relating to that value.

> Factories: Do I really need them?

Yes, and...

> I can go ahead and write an static method within the domain object

... that's fine.  Basic idea: if creating a domain object from so sufficient set of information is complicated, we want that complexity in one place, which can be invoked where we need it.  That doesn't necessarily mean we need a NOUN.  A function is fine.

And, of course, if your domain objects are not complicated, then "just" use the objects constructor/initializer.